# Assign value to the array passed to a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

```
var arrN = [1, 2, 3];

function init(arr){
   arr = [];
   console.log(arrN) //output [1, 2, 3], expect []  
}

init(arrN);
```

When using `splice` or `push` methods the array passed to a function is being modified. So I am trying to understand what is happening when using assignment operator, why it's not changing the array? is it creating the local `var` of the passed array?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference in assigning a different object to a variable or mutating the object currently referenced by a variable.

#### (Re)assigning

When you do an assignment like:

```
arr = []; // or any other value
```

... then the value that `arr` previously had **is not altered**. It is just that `arr` detaches from that previous value and references a new value instead. The original value (if it is an object) lives on, but `arr` no longer has access to it.

Side note: if no other variable references the previous value any more, the garbage collector will at some point in time free the memory used by it. But this is not your case, since the global variable `arrN` still references the original value.

#### Mutating

It is another thing if you don't assign a value to `arr`, but apply instead a *mutation* to it, for instance with `splice`, `push`, `pop`, or an assignment to one of its properties, like `arr[0] = 1` or `arr[1]++`. In those cases, `arr` keeps referencing the same object, and the changes are made to the object it references, which *is* visible to any other variable that references the same object, like `arrN`.

#### Clearing an array

Now if you want to clear the array that is passed to your function, you must avoid to make an assignment like `arr = ...`. Instead, use methods that mutate the array in place:

```
arr.splice(0)
```

Or, alternatively:

```
arr.length = 0;
```

Now you have actually mutated the array, which is also the array referenced by `arrN`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to distinguish between the variable and the actual object (the array). `splice` and `push` are changing the object. 
`arr = []` is just changing the variable, the old object just stays as it is.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, particularly when working with objects the assignment operator (`=`) has three jobs.

1. Assignment
2. Creating a new reference if the right side is an object.
3. Breaking any previous referencing and creating multiple assignments if both sides are objects.

Such as;

```
var a = [1,2,3],   // a is assigned an array
    b = a;         // b is assigned just a reference to a
a = ["a","b","c"]; // b to a referral is now broken
                   // a is assigned with ["a","b","c"]
                   // b is assigned with [1,2,3]
```

same would apply if it was done in reverse order;

```
var a = [1,2,3],   // a is assigned an array
    b = a;         // b is assigned just a reference to a
b = ["a","b","c"]; // b to a referral is now broken
                   // b is assigned with ["a","b","c"]
                   // a keeps it's existing assignment as [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are passing `arrN` to the console instead of passing `arr`. Also, you just call a function by its name, not by the keyword `function`. Here is the corrected code:

```
var arrN = [1, 2, 3];

function init(arr){
   arr = [];
   console.log(arr) 
}

init(arr);
```

You have also declared `init()` with an argument `arr`, which is not needed in this case. What ever the value you pass to `init()`, the value of `arr` will be `[]` because you are reassigning it in the function.